# if can? in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Ruby on Rails application that I inherited from someone, I have code that looks like so

```
<% if can? :create, :objects %>
<%= link_to 'Add New Object', new_object_path %>
```

This web application has a login and users have different permissions that are defined in a table called `groups_roles` (which groups (ex. admin, user) have which roles (ex. add new objects))

I want to add new permissions, so where do I do that at? Where are these things defined? How does Ruby know which table to get the different permissions from, and how does it know what `:create` and `:objects` are in the code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app seems to be using the cancan gem by ryan bates. You can specify the permissions in the `app/models/ability.rb` file.

It simply reads the ability file to determine if a user can perform some action or not. These actions correspond directly to the actions you have defined in the controller class.

Cancan has a great wiki at its github repositiory. Also, the screencast by ryan is an excellent place to start off with.

Comment: that's one way to structure it

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We can place the authorization code directly in models too.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how the application is working, but the `can?` comes from the [cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). See the [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).